# improve efficiency of an exponential string in python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, memory

I've been trying to make a dragon curve fractal in python, and I've gotten as far as 32 iterations, yet 33 gives me a memory error. My computer however is particularly good, a GE75 Raider 9SE, and even with 32 iterations everything is fine. I can run even a 3d modeling software.

I am using 64bit python and have not yet tried allocating more memory or multiprossecing, I still want to see if the efficiency of my actual generation process could be improved. My code so far is as shown:

```
old = 'r'
new = old
table = str.maketrans("lr", "rl")
iteration = 32

for i in range(iteration):
    new = (old) + ('r')
    old = "".join(old[::-1])
    old = old.translate(table)
    new = (new) + (old)
    old = new
```

is one of the things I'm performing redundant? Are one of the functions I'm calling inefficient? I would like to know before I explore more options. I don't make any more copies of this string, so there aren't many unnecessary objects in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think there are too many "inefficiencies" there...  Just lots of memory requirement for the ginormous string you are making.

for every iteration, your string length is roughly doubling, and so is the memory requirement to hold it.

At 30 iterations, the string is roughly 1B characters, which takes about 1GB of RAM to hold.  (Each character is a byte).  You can check this with `sys.getsizeof()` function on your `old` at end of loop.  So, from 30 to 33 iterations is a factor of 8, which gets to 8GB of RAM to hold the result, plus for some period of time before the result is garbage collected, it will hold both `old` and `new` so depending on internals probably some penalty on top of that.

You can search the site for ways to expand your system's allocation for the python virtual machine, which may give you some help, but at the end of the day, do you really need more than 1B elements of the fractal?